# Strange late '90s/early 2000's SF TV movie/episode

Tags: story-identification

I was surfing channels in the early 2000s and happened across the last few minutes of this strange SF program, so I'm not sure just what the plot was. It was definitely made for TV and I am pretty sure it was an episode of an anthology series, although it might have been a TV movie. There was a lot of hand-held camera work and the picture kept shifting from black & white to color. The accents suggest the show was Australian, although I'm not sure about that. The main character is a stunning blonde with smeared crimson lipstick and a gun. She is an android who is programmed to kill. Something has gone wrong with her and she wanders around with a dreamy expression, although she still has time to shoot another woman (or android) in the lady's room. A man from the company that made her appears and tries to talk her into giving up the gun, but she eventually shoots him anyway. They have a casual conversation while he lays dying on the floor. Weird!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an episode of the Australian TV series 'Twisted' titled [Directly From My Heart to You](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734922/?ref_=ttep_ep11). According to IMDB:

> An amoral femme fatale is employed to kill a number of people. It is
> only when she meets her employer that she finds out why and what is
> going on.